# Getting undefined error when using JavaScript map

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am getting "cannot read property of undefined" when using map function over array of objects. As this error only happens when am using external api fetch to get data. If i hardcode the array and do the same thing - am getting result.

This is my data:

```
const ticket= {
  "inventoryId": "2001600236510005688",
  "inventoryItems": [
    {
      "fare": "399.00",
      "passenger": {
        "age": "26",
        "gender": "m",
        "title": "Mr"
      },
      "seatName": "5",
    },
    {
      "fare": "399.00",
      "passenger": {
        "age": "26",
        "title": "Ms",
        "gender": "f",
      },
      "seatName": "6",
    }
  ],
  "serviceCharge": "0.00",
}
```

So my map function is as follows:

```
     const ticket_data = [ticket.inventoryItems].flat();
     ticket_data.map((o,i) => 
             (
                <View key={i}>
                 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                     <View style={{  }}>
                          <Text>Name</Text>
                          <Text>Age</Text>
                          <Text>Gender</Text>
                     </View>
                     <View style={{  }}>
                         <Text>{o.passenger.name}</Text>
                         <Text>{o.passenger.age}</Text>
                         <Text>{o.passenger.gender}</Text>
                      </View>
                 </View>
                                    
                 <View style={{  }}>
                       <Text>Seat: {o.seatName}</Text>
                 </View>
                </View>
             )          
       )
```

Thus am getting error as "cannot read property 'passenger' of undefined" but when i hard code the data and do the same thing - its showing the output ! How to handle this ? And sometime the inventoryItems will be singular object rather that array so need solution for both

And this is React Native code

Comment: What is `ticket_data`? Is it `data.inventoryItems` or something else? If `ticket_data` is empty intially, how will it throw *"cannot read property 'passenger' of undefined"* error?

Comment: check now @adiga

Comment: Nope, am aware of asynchronous calls ! My data list is long am just showing few data points which make error ! I am able to show other datas in the screen ! The only with problem is the above on my question ( In other words, on the same api call am getting multiple datas, and am using that to display but the one with object am getting problem ) @Ivar

Comment: What is the purpose of  `[ticket.inventoryItems].flat();`? It is still unclear how you are getting *"cannot read property 'passenger' of undefined"*.

Comment: can you show the value of `ticket` ?

Comment: As some time the "inventoryItems" will be a single object so am just using flat in order to maintain as array ! @adiga

Comment: @samanthas If you put `console.log(JSON.stringify(ticket_data, null, 2))` before your `.map()`, what does it log?

Comment: My bad, the variable name of array is ticket - i have changed above do check now ! Hope you understand now @adiga

Comment: Kindly do check now, i have updated few things ! name of array const is "ticket" and am using that on the map @adiga

Comment: If hardcoding the object works and when receiving the object from an API doesn't work, the problem is either **the object you receive is not the same structure as the hardcoded one, you are not receiving the object correctly or you are trying to process the object before receiving it**. Have you tried to console.log the received object just before flatenning it? Also, try to add some breakpoints and follow your code execution step by step.

Comment: First it gives "Null" and then it gives the data @Ivar

Comment: @samanthas Do you mean like `[null, {restOfThedata}...`? If so, then that is why it breaks. The first iteration of your `.map()`, `o` is `null` so it cannot read `passenger` from it. You'll need to figure out where that `null` comes from, or if it is correct, build in a check to handle when `o` is `null` (or `undefined`).

Comment: @samanthas then you are making a call BEFORE receiving the data, as you are receiving `null`. Read the `How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?` answers because there's something wrong.

Comment: You probably have some null data in the array. You can either use `o?.passenger?.name` etc to avoid the error. OR you can `filter` before rendering to remove all the null `ticket_data.filter(t => t).map(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably data aren't fetched, while view is rendering. Has `ticket_data` variable default value set to []?

You can check if inventoryItem is array

```
Array.isArray(inventoryItems)
```

Comment: If `ticket_data` is `[]`,how will it throw *"cannot read property 'passenger' of undefined"* error? The callback will be executed on `0` items

Comment: mmm... yes, You're right

Comment: Nope, the datas are fetched ( Am getting other datas in my api - so am sure that the datas are fetched ! ) The problem is with the nested object i believe

Answer (score 0):

[image]I did this:

```
const ticket_data = ticket.inventoryItems;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ticket_data);
    ticket_data.map((k, v) => {
      console.log(k.passenger.title);
    });
  }, []);
```

and got the correct output:

```
Mr
Mrs
```

Note:Ignore the useEffect part.it has nothing to do with your error.
Have added screenshot of the same

Comment: whats the difference ? I have already did this !

Comment: you were doing this `[ticket.inventoryItems].flat();`

Comment: try this `const ticket_data = ticket.inventoryItems;`

Comment: Sometimes i will be getting result as object, in that case i cant map directly and thats why i have used flat

Comment: so first check if the data is an object then use flat else dont use flat